# getting a single xml node - android dev

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to make an app that will use data from an xml database and there are two points where I need help cause I find Java with xml too complicated.

e.g.

```
<items>
<1><name>box</name><price>2.00</price></1>
<2><name>pencil</name><price>1.00</price></1>
</items>
```

1. get a single xml value from a child node(eg.name of 1st item - "box")
2. get an xml database from child nodes (to use it as data source for a listbox) - this one is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that XML nodes must be named starting with a letter - just like variables in Java. Try something like the following:

```
<items>
    <item name="box" price="2.00" />
    <item name="pencil" price="1.00" />
</items>
```

So you see, each `item` is denoted as an `<item>`. In XML, the tag has semantic meaning. You can them do something like (depending on your parser - this is actually closer to JavaScript but I hope you can get the idea):

```
myXmlDocument = parseThatXMLForMePlease(); // Load the XMl from wherever
itemList = myXmlDocument.getChildren()[0]; // Get the first node in the document
firstItem = itemList.getChildren()[0];     // Get the first child of the item list
itemName = firstItem.getAttr("name");
itemPrice = firstItem.getAttr("price");
```

If you want to use the data as the basis for some listbox, you will probably want to use an [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html). This is basically a datastructure designed for serving up data to some UI widget (the link points to a ListAdapter - which sounds like exactly what you want).